# В longblob вместо массива байт записывается null MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, asp.net-web-api

У меня есть метод в web-api, который отправляет 2 массива байт в базу данных (MYSQL), типы полей longblob. В одно поле(Avatar) приходит массив на 7156 байт, и все прекрасное записывается и отображается, во второе поле(Passport) приходит массив 317611 байт, но этот массив не записывается, а вместо него — null. **ТИП ПОЛЯ ТОЧНО LONGBLOB**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Guest>(entity =>{
entity.Property(e => e.Avatar).HasColumnType("longbob");
entity.Property(e => e.Passport).HasColumnType("longbob");

entity.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany(p => p.Guests)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull)
    .HasConstraintName("FK_PGUserId");});
```

Сначала была создана база данных, контекст данных и mapping был создан с помощью команды "Scaffold-DbContext "connection-string" MySql.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir sakila -f". Но изначально полей Avatar и Passport там не было, я решила прописать их вручную. Но это не помогло. Также решила сделать миграцию и обновить базу, но это тоже не помогло.

Сам метод

```
[HttpPost]
public void SavePictures([FromBody] Request value)
var guest = new Guest();
guest.Avatar = value.AvatarBytes;
guest.Passport = value.PassportBytes;
_dbContext.Guests.Add(guest);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

К нему точно прилетает не пустые значение, к нему приходят массивы байт.

Также я могу непосредственно в саму бд загрузить изображение и всё нормально сохранится. Получается, что проблема в самом web-api.

в чем может быть проблема? буду рада любой помощи

Comment: HasColumnType("longbob") ? Может быть longblob? Что видно при отладке в value.AvatarBytes и в value.PassportBytes? Правильно ли я понимаю, что у Вас проблема с avatar и passport? Если "да", то уберите не относящиеся к вопросу поля, которые запутывают/мешают. Также в таком случае не мешало бы обновить вопрос, добавив в него информацию о том, с какими свойствами/полями/столбцами у Вас возникает проблема.

Comment: Если изменить запрос так, чтоб в Passport "прилетало" не 317611 байт, а намного меньше (к примеру то-же самое что и в Avatar)? Работает в таком случае?

Comment: @XelaNimed, опечатку я исправила, но по-прежнему не работает. Да, проблемы с avatar и passport. При отладке в value.AvatarBytes и в value.PassportBytes находятся массивы байтов. Если вместо 317611 отправить 7156  байт (та же картинка, что и в первом массиве), то все работает. Вообще в базу данных не хотят записываться массивы больше 8 кб

Comment: @XelaNimed, я пробовала сделать еще одно web-api, но только сначала написать код, а потом сделать миграцию. Там точно написано longblob, опечаток нет. Но там тоже это не сработало. Меня просто смущает, что я могу сама принудительно в самой базе данных сохранить это большое изображение, но через api это сделать не получается. Может ли быть такое, что не у базу данных, а у соединения есть ограничения на размер передаваемой информации?

Comment: Странное поведение... Если посмотреть на максимальные значения blob в MySql, то даже обычный BLOB поддерживает до 64Кб. И так... В отладке Вы убедились, что данные корректно приходят (и не "обрезаются"), в [БД типы](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings) проверили, типы в классах проверили, ограничений на максимальную длину в модели данных нет. Единственное, что приходит на ум, так это проверить в конфигурации параметр maxRequestLength, например [как здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69931152/3129992).

Comment: в файле appsettings.json есть параметр MaxRequestBodySize, который по дефолту равен 104857600 байтам. Плюс, кстати, картинки нормально могут сохраняться в папку, и большие и маленькие, проблем никаких не возникает. Может, всё-таки, дело в соединении? или такого просто быть не может?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я попробовала создать контекст базы данных с помощью библиотеки **Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql**, а не **MySql.EntityFrameworkCore** и всё четко работает. Вчера ночью меня посетила эта мысль, что если в коде ошибок нет, в базе данных тоже, то значит, что проблема может быть в библиотеке:)